# Jquery: select.children[index] faster than nth-child selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

In jquery, say I have an html selector *select*. Which is faster to get the ith element from the selector? If one is faster, how much faster? By a little or a lot?

```
select.children[i]
```

Or

```
$j('*:nth-child(' + i + ')', select)
```

Comment: May I suggest visiting [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/)? It'll allow you to benchmark performance of JavaScript quite easily.

Comment: Well, why don't you just time it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select.children[i]` is way faster. This is because it doesn't have the overhead of jQuery. Here's a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/vanilla-vs-jquery), where you can see the results.

For the first test i used

```
var select = document.getElementById('select'); 
var option = select.children[2];
```

And the second

```
var select = document.getElementById('select'); 
var option = $('*:nth-child(' + 2 + ')', select);
```

Comment: Even using jQuery for both, the index method (select.children()[i]) is about twice as fast.

Comment: Really? I'm getting some contradictory results, check out the updated jsperf i added some more tests.

Comment: Just ran your perf (Fx 8) and the `$...children()[i]` was actually about three times faster than the `nth-child` variation. My perf was only about two times: http://jsperf.com/index-or-n-th-child-jquery